# Non-rectangular pick of elements of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

How to pick elements of a matrix that are inside a circle centered at the center of the matrix?

Comment: Please add the code you already have tried and the results, if any, that you already have obtained.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Select` to choose the elements which are within a circular distance from the center.  Let's assume you have a square matrix,

```
nElements = 12;
radius = 4;
matrix = RandomReal[1, {nElements, nElements}];
center = (Dimensions@matrix + 1)/2;
```

Then you can generate a list of the matrix elements with

```
Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {nElements, nElements}], 1]
(* {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{1,7},{1,8},{1,9},{1,10},{1,11},{1,12},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{2,7},{2,8},{2,9},{2,10},{2,11},{2,12},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6},{3,7},{3,8},{3,9},{3,10},{3,11},{3,12},{4,1},{4,2},{4,3},{4,4},{4,5},{4,6},{4,7},{4,8},{4,9},{4,10},{4,11},{4,12},{5,1},{5,2},{5,3},{5,4},{5,5},{5,6},{5,7},{5,8},{5,9},{5,10},{5,11},{5,12},{6,1},{6,2},{6,3},{6,4},{6,5},{6,6},{6,7},{6,8},{6,9},{6,10},{6,11},{6,12},{7,1},{7,2},{7,3},{7,4},{7,5},{7,6},{7,7},{7,8},{7,9},{7,10},{7,11},{7,12},{8,1},{8,2},{8,3},{8,4},{8,5},{8,6},{8,7},{8,8},{8,9},{8,10},{8,11},{8,12},{9,1},{9,2},{9,3},{9,4},{9,5},{9,6},{9,7},{9,8},{9,9},{9,10},{9,11},{9,12},{10,1},{10,2},{10,3},{10,4},{10,5},{10,6},{10,7},{10,8},{10,9},{10,10},{10,11},{10,12},{11,1},{11,2},{11,3},{11,4},{11,5},{11,6},{11,7},{11,8},{11,9},{11,10},{11,11},{11,12},{12,1},{12,2},{12,3},{12,4},{12,5},{12,6},{12,7},{12,8},{12,9},{12,10},{12,11},{12,12}} *)
```

And then choose those elements which are within a certain radius of the center, by using `Norm` to compute the distance and `Select` to choose the elements,

```
circleElements = 
 Select[Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {nElements, nElements}], 1], 
  Norm[# - center] <= radius &]
```

(some of you may be thinking it would be faster to use a circular region and then apply `RegionFunction` or `Element` to it, and you would be wrong).

You can use `Extract` to grab those elements which are within the circular area,

```
Extract[matrix, circleElements]
(*{0.0992023,0.495438,0.414766,0.120624,0.359152,0.886304,0.852727,0.456035,0.870987,0.818563,0.339816,0.809685,0.776808,0.307547,0.831416,0.19712,0.200391,0.505536,0.879347,0.155195,0.876139,0.703026,0.335968,0.912485,0.458875,0.220671,0.723213,0.565869,0.601153,0.737624,0.990036,0.428771,0.931505,0.905728,0.303853,0.612953,0.00655347,0.929123,0.837107,0.786894,0.308131,0.377017,0.17553,0.669582,0.914713,0.802992,0.702451,0.304244,0.104606,0.726116,0.352679,0.288495} *)
```

Finally you can use `ReplacePart` to change those elements to some other value,

```
{MatrixPlot[matrix],
 MatrixPlot[ReplacePart[matrix, circleElements -> 0]]}
```

[image]

Or, if you want to keep only those elements **inside** the circle, I can think of two ways to do it.  First, you could do like above but change the $\leq$ to a $>$,

```
outsideCircleElements = 
  Select[Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {nElements, nElements}], 1], 
   Norm[# - center] > radius &];
MatrixPlot[ReplacePart[matrix, outsideCircleElements -> 0]]
```

[image]

Or you could create an array of zeroes, and then change the center elements to the values for the original matrix,

```
newmatrix = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@matrix];
Set[newmatrix[[#1, #2]], matrix[[#1, #2]]] & @@@ circleElements;
MatrixPlot[newmatrix]
```

Both give the same result.

You can apply this to larger matrices,

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually want to extract those values which are in the circle instead of assigning them as zeros. How can I do that?
I used EXTRACT by the way.

Comment: @faf - see the edit, you want to use `Extract`

Comment: D'oh, didn't fully read your comment I reckon - so my point was that you can use the code above to create a list of the element positions which are within a circular area of the center.  So the line `Extract[matrix, circleElements]` gives you these in a list.  Is that what you were going for?

Comment: How can I assign these new extracted values to a new matrix with dimenssion of the first matrix and assign the non-circleElement to zero?(So one sees the position of circleElements in a matrix)

Comment: @faf - see the edit, I think this should do what you are asking.

Comment: I can't vote up yet due to lack of reputation, but thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries, but if that answers the question, you can click the check mark next to it so it isn't still listed with the unsolved questions.  Also, welcome to the site, take the [tour].  And if you have any more questions come on back.  Try to be very specific about what you are asking - we probably could have gone straight to the answer you wanted, but it wasn't totaly clear to me what that was.

Answer (score 8):

Why reinvent the wheel?  The built-in function `DiskMatrix` returns a matrix whose values are `1`s within a particular radius of its center:

```
diskmat = DiskMatrix[3, {10, 20}];
diskmat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

You can then use `Pick` to select the appropriate elements from the input matrix, and `Flatten` to turn them into a simple list.  Packaging it all up:

```
selectdiskmatrix[mat_, r_] := Flatten[Pick[mat, DiskMatrix[r, Dimensions[mat]], 1]]

testmat = Table[i + j, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 20}];
selectdiskmatrix[testmat, 3]

(* {12, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 14, 
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20} *)
```

This works for both square and non-square matrices.  If you wanted an off-center disk, you would have to create a disk matrix and then pad it with zeroes appropriately;  but other than that, the same technique should work.

Comment: Didn't know about `DiskMatrix`! Also `Pick` should be very fast here.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: Yeah, the primary use of `DiskMatrix` is (I think) in image processing, which makes its intended use somewhat specialized.  But that doesn't stop us from using it here.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I really like this, better than my answer, but I don't know that `Pick` is doing what the OP is looking for (it wasn't clear in the original question).  I think that would be achieved by `selectdiskmatrix[mat_, r_] := 
 ReplacePart[mat, Position[DiskMatrix[r, Dimensions@mat], 0] -> 0]`

Comment: @JasonB:  Actually, the easier way to get that output would be to just use  element-by-element multiplication:  `mat * DiskMatrix[r, Dimensions@mat] `.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that is definitely less readable and intuitive than JasonB's answer, but a good deal faster, especially if the radius is small. Of course speed may not be important in this case, but I'm posting it anyway :)

The idea is to create a ragged `Table` where, for each row `i`, the included columns range from `jmin` to `jmax` given by the solutions to the disk edge equation

```
(j - jc)^2 == radius^2 - (i - ic)^2
```

where `ic`, `jc` are the center positions. The solutions will be

```
jmin = Ceiling[- Sqrt[radius^2 - (i - ic)^2] + jc]
jmax = Floor[- Sqrt[radius^2 - (i - ic)^2] + jc]
```

`Ceiling` and `Floor` makes sure we are inside the disk and that the indices are in fact integers.

The matrix elements are found by the function

```
elements[mat_, center_, radius_] := 
Block[{ic, jc},
  {ic, jc} = center;
  Table[mat[[i, Ceiling[-# + jc] ;; Floor[# + jc]]] & @
    Sqrt[radius^2 - (i - ic)^2]
  , {i, Ceiling[-radius + ic], Floor[radius + ic]}
  ]
]
```

and the positions by

```
indices[mat_, center_, radius_] :=
Block[{ic, jc, row},
  {ic, jc} = center;
  Flatten[
    Table[(row = Range[Ceiling[-# + jc], Floor[# + jc]]; 
      Transpose[{ConstantArray[i, Length@row], row}]) &[
      Sqrt[radius^2 - (i - ic)^2]],
    {i, Ceiling[-radius + ic], Floor[radius + ic]}
    ]
  , 1]
]
```

The reason it is faster is that the index `i` only runs over those rows that are actually inside the disk, so especially for small values of `radius`, this is faster than running through all rows. Also we do not need to perform any testing with this algorithm.

As with JasonB's answer, this also works fine for non-square matrices:

```
radius = 30;
matrix = RandomReal[1, {200, 400}];
center = {150, 250}

First@AbsoluteTiming[ind = indices[matrix, center, radius]];
(* 0.003351 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[circleElements = 
  Select[Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {200, 400}], 1], 
  Norm[# - center] <= radius &];
(* 1.641141 *)
```

The plots produced are of course identical:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access an entry (n,m) of a Matrix by

```
M[[n,m]]
```

So you could get the circle around the coordinates "center" of radius r by

```
{M[[center+r,center-r]],M[[center+r,center]],M[[center+r,center+r]]},
```

and so on.

Or as a function

```
circle[M_, center_, radius_] :=Table[M[[n, m]], {n, center - radius,center + radius}, {m,center - radius, center + radius}]
```

Comment: This produces a new square, with corners located at the limits of your `Table` iterator specs...